# JavaScript Non-regex Replace

Tags: javascript

Do any of the existing JavaScript frameworks have a non-regex `replace()` function,
or has this already been posted on the web somewhere as a one-off function?

For example I want to replace `"@!#$123=%"` and I don't want to worry about which characters to escape. Most languages seem to have both methods of doing replacements. I would like to see this simple thing added.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

i may be misunderstanding your question, but javascript does have a [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var string = '@!#$123=%';
var newstring = string.replace('@!#$123=%', 'hi');
```

**edit**: (see comments) the 5th edition does seem to have this info in it, although it doesn't show up when i [link directly](http://safari.informit.com/0596101996/jscript5-CHP-11-SECT-2) to it. here's the relevant part:

> The replace( ) method performs a search-and-replace operation. It takes a regular expression as its first argument and a replacement string as its second argument. It searches the string on which it is called for matches with the specified pattern. If the regular expression has the g flag set, the replace( ) method replaces all matches in the string with the replacement string; otherwise, it replaces only the first match it finds. **If the first argument to replace( ) is a string rather than a regular expression, the method searches for that string literally rather than converting it to a regular expression with the RegExp( ) constructor, as search( ) does.**

Comment: huh. maybe I was looking at an old version of "Javascript: The Definitive Guide" that only showed the regex example. so I never tried the above code. now I feel really dumb. -10 cool points for me.

Comment: Can someone check the most recent version of "Javascript: The Definitive Guide"? Is this kind of example now included?

Comment: Nick's answer below is more reliable for a "No-regex" option because the native replace method uses special characters in the *replace* string. So while replacing text with 'hi' is fine, replacing with anything containing '$' could cause unexpected results. Try "a".replace("a","$$b") as an example :)

Comment: The javascript  function replaces only the first entry

Comment: This answer is answers the OP fine. The key is that `replace()` treats a _string_ search value as a literal string. "$" is not treated specially, in that case. If, `RegExp()` is explicitly called, that has nothing to do with `replace()` since a RegExp object is being passed to `replace()`, not a string.

Answer (score 23):

I had exactly the same problem searching for a non-regex javascript string replace() method. My solution was to use a combination of split() and join():

```
"some text containing regex interpreted characters: $1.00".split("$").join("£");
```

which gives:

> "some text containing regex interpreted characters: £1.00"

compare with replace():

```
"some text containing regex interpreted characters: $1.00".replace(new RegExp("$"),"£")
```

which bizarrely gives:

> "some text containing regex interpreted characters: $1.00£"

Comment: Not enough examples online would show you the simple replace method - "some text containing regex interpreted characters: $1.00".replace("$","£");

Comment: That's web programming: reinventing the wheel. JavaScript's `replace()` is a bad joke. Thanks for this hack. I think it's the best solution. +1

Comment: «$» means end of line in regular expression! So there's nothing strange with `RegExp("$")` which matches the end of your line as expected. You should have escaped your dollar before sending it to RegExp: `RegExp("\$")`

Comment: Note:  this neatly replaces ALL occurrences. So `s.split("$").join("£")` is equivalent to `s.replace(/\$/g, "£")` or `s.replace(RegExp("\\$", "g"), "£")`.

Answer (score 6):

You'll still need to replace a few dollar sign combinations as specified on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

This produces `$bc` not `$$bc`

```js
'abc'.replace('a', '$$')
```

The best way to not worry about this is to use the function replace:

```js
'abc'.replace('a', () => '$$')
```

Comment: This seems to be, by far, the best and simplest solution to this problem.  It worked great for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function replaceAllTemp(str,find, replace) { 
var ignoreCase=true;
var _token;
var token=find;
var newToken=replace;
var i = -1;

if ( typeof token === "string" ) {

    if ( ignoreCase ) {

        _token = token.toLowerCase();

        while( (
            i = str.toLowerCase().indexOf(
                token, i >= 0 ? i + newToken.length : 0
            ) ) !== -1
        ) {
            str = str.substring( 0, i ) +
                newToken +
                str.substring( i + token.length );
        }

    } else {
        return this.split( token ).join( newToken );
    }

}
return str;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with or without ignoring case sensitivity. 
Sadly, JavaScript's indexOf doesn't take locale vs. invariant as argument, so you'll have to replace `toLowerCase` with `toLocaleLowerCase` if you want to preserve culture-specifity.

```
function replaceAll(str, find, newToken, ignoreCase)
{
    var i = -1;

    if (!str)
    {
        // Instead of throwing, act as COALESCE if find == null/empty and str == null
        if ((str == null) && (find == null))
            return newToken;

        return str;
    }

    if (!find) // sanity check 
        return str;

    ignoreCase = ignoreCase || false;
    find = ignoreCase ? find.toLowerCase() : find;

    while ((
        i = (ignoreCase ? str.toLowerCase() : str).indexOf(
            find, i >= 0 ? i + newToken.length : 0
        )) !== -1
    )
    {
        str = str.substring(0, i) +
            newToken +
            str.substring(i + find.length);
    } // Whend 

    return str;
}
```

or as prototype:

```
if (!String.prototype.replaceAll ) {  
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (find, replace) {
    var str = this, i = -1;

    if (!str)
    {
        // Instead of throwing, act as COALESCE if find == null/empty and str == null
        if ((str == null) && (find == null))
            return newToken;

        return str;
    }

    if (!find) // sanity check 
        return str;

    ignoreCase = ignoreCase || false;
    find = ignoreCase ? find.toLowerCase() : find;

    while ((
        i = (ignoreCase ? str.toLowerCase() : str).indexOf(
            find, i >= 0 ? i + newToken.length : 0
        )) !== -1
    )
    {
        str = str.substring(0, i) +
            newToken +
            str.substring(i + find.length);
    } // Whend 

    return str;
};
}
```

Comment: Regex offers word boundary options with \b. Is there a way to modify this to not replace if the next character is alphanumeric?

Comment: or if you have any tips to add this ability