# Multiple Keyword Replacement from multiple List

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, substitution, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm editing a 30 Day posting template for work. I've posted each day to a cell in Column A.

Each day may contain [keyword1] and/or [keyword2]. I have to replace keyword1 based off a list, we will name ListA, subsequently, I need to replace keyword2 based off ListB.

I've looked around online and even saw something similar here on Stack. The solution provided on [Google Sheets multiple search and replace from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411105/google-sheets-multiple-search-and-replace-from-a-list) works wonderfully as mentioned, I'm working on a template and would like to be able to replace [keyword1] down the 30 cells with the keywords in ListA uniquely, same with keyword2 from ListB

I don't know where to begin honestly, I've tried copy-pasting 30 times keyword1 and then pasted the 30 keywords beside it. But all it does is just replaces keyword1 from the first keyword in the list down all 30 entries.

code used:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, List!A1, List!B1), List!A2, List!B2), List!A3, List!B3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, "k1", "LA"), "k2", "LB"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

So after some more experimenting, I felt stupid for not realizing that I could simply change the range within the formula given from a previous solution.

so based on the previous solution found in another similar question:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, List!A1, List!B1), List!A2, List!B2), List!A3, List!B3))
```

it becomes:

formula(for keyword1)

Keyword1 was listed in column A and

ListA was listed in column B

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A31, List!A1:A31, List!B1:B31), List!A2, List!B2), List!A3, List!B3))
```

and

formula(for keyword2)

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1:B31, List!C1:C31, List!D1:D31), List!C2, List!D2), List!C3, List!D3))
```

Keyword2 was listed in column C and

ListB was listed in column D