# Google Sheets multiple search and replace from a list with repeated strings

Tags: regex, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace

I've implemented the solution at 
[Google Sheets multiple search and replace from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411105/google-sheets-multiple-search-and-replace-from-a-list) for a similar issue.

I'm using the script

```
function preg_quote( str ) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // +   original by: booeyOH
  // +   improved by: Ates Goral (http://magnetiq.com)
  // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  // *     example 1: preg_quote("$40");
  // *     returns 1: '\$40'
  // *     example 2: preg_quote("*RRRING* Hello?");
  // *     returns 2: '\*RRRING\* Hello\?'
  // *     example 3: preg_quote("\\.+*?[^]$(){}=!<>|:");
  // *     returns 3: '\\\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:'

  return (str+'').replace(/([\\\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:])/g, "\\$1");
}

function ARRAYREPLACE(input,fromList,toList,caseSensitive){
  /* default behavior it is not case sensitive */
  if( caseSensitive == undefined ){
    caseSensitive = false;
  }
  /* if the from list it is not a list, become a list */
  if( typeof fromList != "object" ) {
    fromList = [ fromList ];
  }
  /* if the to list it is not a list, become a list */
  if( typeof toList != "object" ) {
    toList = [ toList ];
  }
  /* force the input be a string */
  var result = input.toString();

  /* iterates using the max size */
  var bigger  = Math.max( fromList.length, toList.length) ;

  /* defines the words separators */
  var arrWordSeparator = [ ".", ",", ";", " " ];

  /* interate into the lists */
  for(var i = 0; i < bigger; i++ ) {
    /* get the word that should be replaced */
    var fromValue = fromList[ ( i % ( fromList.length ) ) ]
    /* get the new word that should replace */
    var toValue = toList[ ( i % ( toList.length ) ) ]

    /* do not replace undefined */
    if ( fromValue == undefined ) {
      continue;
    }
    if ( toValue == undefined ) {
      toValue = "";
    }

    /* apply case sensitive rule */
    var caseRule = "g";
    if( !caseSensitive ) {
      /* make the regex case insensitive */
      caseRule = "gi";
    }

    /* for each end word char, make the replacement and update the result */
    for ( var j = 0; j < arrWordSeparator.length; j++ ) {

      /* from value being the first word of the string */
      result =  result.replace( new RegExp( "^(" + preg_quote( fromValue + arrWordSeparator[ j ] ) + ")" , caseRule ), toValue + arrWordSeparator[ j ] );

      /* from value being the last word of the string */
      result =  result.replace( new RegExp( "(" + preg_quote( arrWordSeparator[ j ] + fromValue ) + ")$" , caseRule ), arrWordSeparator[ j ] + toValue );

      /* from value in the middle of the string between two word separators */
      for ( var k = 0; k < arrWordSeparator.length; k++ ) {
        result =  result.replace( 
          new RegExp( 
            "(" + preg_quote( arrWordSeparator[ j ] + fromValue + arrWordSeparator[ k ] ) + ")" , 
            caseRule 
          ), 
          /* need to keep the same word separators */
          arrWordSeparator[ j ] + toValue + arrWordSeparator[ k ] 
        );
      }
    }

    /* from value it is the only thing in the string */
    result =  result.replace( new RegExp( "^(" + preg_quote( fromValue ) + ")$" , caseRule ), toValue );
  }
  /* return the new result */
  return result;
}
```

An example input is;

> "
>
> DETAILS
>
> - halter neck style
> - sleeveless
> - detachable
>     waist tie
> - gathered tiered skirt panels
> - invisible
>     back zip
> - back neck opening with button close
> - unlined
>
> SIZING
>
> - model is 170cm and wears a size 8
> - garment flat
>     measurements:
>   - size 8 length - 139cm, waist - 33cm,
>       bust - 43cm
>   - size 10 length - 141cm, waist - 35cm, bust -
>       45cm
>   - size 12 length - 143cm, waist - 37cm, bust - 47cm
>   - size 14 length - 145cm, waist - 38cm, bust - 48cm
> - model stats: bust - 76cm, waist - 57cm, hips - 91cm
>
> GARMENT CARE
>
> - material - rayon
> - cold hand wash separately
>
> "

and the replacement list is at;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MxaZ1Jki1fnVw6jfFllur2BpPN6-6b6fAmLSKQniG-8/edit#gid=0

However my results are only showing a conversion of some of the strings. Below is the output;

> "
>
> DETAILS
>
> - halter neck style
> - sleeveless
> - detachable
>     waist tie
> - gathered tiered skirt panels
> - invisible
>     back zip
> - back neck opening with button close
> - unlined
>
> SIZING
>
> - model is 5' 6"" and wears a size 8
> - garment flat
>     measurements:
>   - size 8 length - 54.5"", waist - 13"",
>       bust - 43cm
>   - size 10 length - 55.5"", waist - 14"", bust -
>       45cm
>   - size 12 length - 56.5"", waist - 14.5"", bust -
>       47cm
>   - size 14 length - 57"", waist - 15"", bust - 48cm
> - model stats: bust - 30"", waist - 22.5"", hips - 91cm
>
> GARMENT CARE
>
> - material - rayon
> - cold hand wash separately
>
> "

The third instance of the dimensions on each line is being ignored, as are the sizes entirely. Could anyone tell me if the script limited to a certain number of replacements, or any changes I should make to replace the sizes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing the code the problems seems to be with the values at the end of a line. If you have your input defined as a multi-line JavaScript string make sure that you leave a  space after those values.

```js
var input = "\
DETAILS\
\
halter neck style\
sleeveless\
detachable waist tie\
gathered tiered skirt panels\
invisible back zip\
back neck opening with button close\
unlined\
SIZING\
\
model is 170cm and wears a size 8\
garment flat measurements:\
size 8 length - 139cm, waist - 33cm, bust - 43cm \ //Notice the space after "cm"
size 10 length - 141cm, waist - 35cm, bust - 45cm \
size 12 length - 143cm, waist - 37cm, bust - 47cm \
size 14 length - 145cm, waist - 38cm, bust - 48cm \
model stats: bust - 76cm, waist - 57cm, hips - 91cm \
GARMENT CARE\
\
material - rayon\
cold hand wash separately\
";
```

If you are reading this input through a file, probably the problem is related to a new line (`\n`) or a carriage return (`\r`), I would add those values in the `arrWordSeparator` variable to take care of multi-line inputs. So it would look something similar to this:

```
 /* defines the words separators */
  var arrWordSeparator = [ ".", ",", ";", " ", "\n", "\r" ];
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the right approach. As it was html there was a unordered list element at the start and end of the line. Adding these variables as the `arrWordSeparator` definition resolved the issue. Appreciate the assistance.