# How to use custom function ARRAYREPLACE() in a array formula? [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using [Thiago Mata's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456164/thiago-mata) custom Google Sheets function to search and replace multiple words in  a string.

Thiago's function is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411105/google-sheets-multiple-search-and-replace-from-a-list)

Practically speaking, I'm using his function for replacing keywords with their corresponding hyperlinks.

The original strings are stored in column Examples!A:A. The "keyword-replacement html" pairs are stored in three other sheets: 'Verticals', 'Horizontals', and 'Technologies'.

For example, each instance of "Authors" found in the original string is replaced with

```html
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.flauntmydesign.com/authors" title="Click for more business examples targeting authors">Authors</a>
```

[Here is a Google Sheet showing what I'm trying to do](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ymFhSSdppLDezqybFDWsofC-Wm7Yb5fpbH9mYzHMSr4/edit?usp=sharing)
(editable outside the original data/formulas)

This keyword replacement works great when I apply the function to a single cell. It also works great when I manually drag the formula down the column.

The question is, how do I turn column Examples!B:B into a working array formula?

Comment: Can you please clarify the input data and the desired output? Please consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information, clearly indicating those.

Comment: The spreadsheet you provided is not public. Can you make it publicly accessible? Also, if you do that, leave a comment saying that you did it so that people can notice that.

Comment: I made the spreadsheet public, and it's now editable outside the original data/formulas.

Comment: Hi, I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66917038). Could you please confirm whether that solves your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify `ARRAYREPLACE` so that it receives a range of cells instead of a single cell. Then, iterate through the array (for example, using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) and, for each row, use the code corresponding to your previous function:

```
function ARRAYREPLACE(dataInput,fromList,toList){
  return dataInput.map(row => {
    const input = row[0];
    // ... YOUR PREVIOUS FUNCTION
    return result;
  })
}
```

Then, in `B2`, instead of setting the input range to `A2`, set it to `A2:A10`:

[image]

#### Full code:

```js
 
function ARRAYREPLACE(dataInput,fromList,toList,caseSensitive){
  /* solution from Iamblichus */
return dataInput.map(row => {
const input = row[0];
  
  /* default behavior it is not case sensitive */
  if( caseSensitive == undefined ){
caseSensitive = false;
  }
  /* if the from list it is not a list, become a list */
  if( typeof fromList != "object" ) {
fromList = [ fromList ];
  }
  /* if the to list it is not a list, become a list */
  if( typeof toList != "object" ) {
toList = [ toList ];
  }
  /* force the input be a string */
  var result = input.toString();

  /* iterates using the max size */
  var bigger  = Math.max( fromList.length, toList.length) ;

  /* defines the words separators */
  var arrWordSeparator = [ ".", ",", ";", ":", " " ];

  /* interate into the lists */
  for(var i = 0; i < bigger; i++ ) {
/* get the word that should be replaced */
var fromValue = fromList[ ( i % ( fromList.length ) ) ]
/* get the new word that should replace */
var toValue = toList[ ( i % ( toList.length ) ) ]

/* do not replace undefined */
if ( fromValue == undefined ) {
  continue;
}
if ( toValue == undefined ) {
  toValue = "";
}

/* apply case sensitive rule */
var caseRule = "g";
if( !caseSensitive ) {
  /* make the regex case insensitive */
  caseRule = "gi";
}

/* for each end word char, make the replacement and update the result */
for ( var j = 0; j < arrWordSeparator.length; j++ ) {

  /* from value being the first word of the string */
  result =  result.replace( new RegExp( "^(" + preg_quote( fromValue + arrWordSeparator[ j ] ) + ")" , caseRule ), toValue + arrWordSeparator[ j ] );

  /* from value being the last word of the string */
  result =  result.replace( new RegExp( "(" + preg_quote( arrWordSeparator[ j ] + fromValue ) + ")$" , caseRule ), arrWordSeparator[ j ] + toValue );

  /* from value in the middle of the string between two word separators */
  for ( var k = 0; k < arrWordSeparator.length; k++ ) {
    result =  result.replace( 
      new RegExp( 
        "(" + preg_quote( arrWordSeparator[ j ] + fromValue + arrWordSeparator[ k ] ) + ")" , 
        caseRule 
      ), 
      /* need to keep the same word separators */
      arrWordSeparator[ j ] + toValue + arrWordSeparator[ k ] 
    );
  }
}

/* from value it is the only thing in the string */
result =  result.replace( new RegExp( "^(" + preg_quote( fromValue ) + ")$" , caseRule ), toValue );
  }
  /* return the new result */
  return result;
  })
}
```

And call it like this:

#### Formula:

```
=arrayreplace(arrayreplace(arrayreplace($A2:A10,Verticals!$A:$A,Verticals!$B:$B),Horizontals!$A:$A,Horizontals!$B:$B),Technologies!$A:$A,Technologies!$B:$B)
```

Comment: Thanks @lamblichus! I tried to modify ARRAYREPLACE(), but I get an error message: "Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 92 file: Code.gs" when trying to save the modified function.

Comment: @Tomas, you are not copying the function correctly (nor calling it correctly in the sheets, at least in the sheet you provided). I'll update my answer now with the full code snippet.

Comment: @Tomas `return result` was already part of your original function, it was not meant to be repeated. Please check the section `Full code` of my updated answer. Also, the way you call the function in the sheets doesn't require using `ARRAYFORMULA`. I added that to my answer too (section `Formula`). Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Iamblichus! This works! :)