# Google Sheets multiple search and replace from a list

Tags: list, google-apps-script, google-sheets, search, replace

I already found this solution, but unfortunately I can't comment or ask a question in this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47685929/19554304

Is there a way to change the script from the solution so that it is possible to check multiple words for a replacement. For example: Check if the text contains the words A or B and replace them with C.

Thx

Check if the text contains the words A or B and replace them with C.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it vía formula like this:

```
=reduce(C2,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)),LAMBDA(a,r,REGEXREPLACE(a,"\b("&INDEX(A:A,r)&")\b",INDEX(B:B,r,))))
```

You put the values separated by "|" in Column A and its replacements in column B. For example: "car|Moto"

Let me know if it is useful! You can use it as ARRAYFORMULA too by wrapping it in ARRAYFORMULA and changing C2 with the whole range of C column